# Is it good convention using post title's in permalink?

Tags: wordpress

Presently i am using post-names in my permalink eg:-domain.com/post-name but I wanted to know can we use post-titles in place of post-name eg:-domain.com/post-title.

Comment: What's the difference between post name and post title?

Comment: post title is the original title entered by me and post name is the slug of the title I entered

Comment: Then use the slug in your permalinks. That's what it's for.

Comment: I m using the slug, but the client wants me to display the original title not the slug, thats is the reason i want to confirm whether doing it is  good convention

Comment: I would say it's bad practice. Explain to the client why the slug exists.

Comment: Wish they were as sensible,btw thank for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `post-name` slug for the URL, it's what it's there for. The `post-title` will likely contain spaces and potentially other special characters which are not suitable for URLs. For SEO purposes you should also consider sites that will autolink URLs to your site, consider the following for a page named "My Page":

http://example.com/my-page (uses slug)

http://example.com/My Page (uses title, notice the broken link)

http://example.com/My%20Page (uses encoded title, which is hard to read)

Comment: i know that usingpost-name(slug) is the best option and secure too as no 2 slugs can be same but my client is what i can say stupid and he simply wants the title :(

Comment: If the question is "is it good convention" the answer is no. If it's "how would i do it" then the answer is "inefficiently and error prone" but you can use a `add_filter('request', 'your_function');` to parse the querystring, look up the page/post by name and then set the proper ID/slug back to they query. I really recommend against it though.

Comment: I would also say that your client hired you to do something they don't know how to do, it's your responsibility to tell them how it should be done and why.